# Notion API from Vercel Edge Runtime responds 400

Tags: next.js, vercel, notion-api

From API routes of Next.js on [Vercel Edge Runtime](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/functions/edge-functions/edge-functions-api), Notion API, eg: [Retrieve a database](https://developers.notion.com/reference/retrieve-a-database) or [Query a database](https://developers.notion.com/reference/post-database-query), responds 400 invalid_request_url as follows:

```json
{"object":"error","status":400,"code":"invalid_request_url","message":"Invalid request URL."}
```

From the local environment (`next dev`, `vercel dev`), Notion API responds 200 properly.

Codes are as follows:

**Retrieve a database**

```js
import { NextRequest } from 'next/server'

export const config = { runtime: 'edge' }

async function(req: NextRequest) {
  const url = `https://api.notion.com/v1/databases/${DATABASE_ID}`
  const headers = {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${NOTION_API_SECRET}`,
      'Notion-Version': '2022-06-28',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }

  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: headers,
  })

  const data = await response.json()
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
}
```

**Query a database**

```js
import { NextRequest } from 'next/server'

export const config = { runtime: 'edge' }

async function(req: NextRequest) {
  const { searchParams } = new URL(req.url);

  if (!searchParams.has('slug')) {
    throw new Error('No slug in searchParams.')
  }

  const slug = searchParams.get('slug').trim()

  const url = `https://api.notion.com/v1/databases/${DATABASE_ID}/query`
  const body = JSON.stringify({
      filter: {
        and: [
          { property: 'Published', checkbox: { equals: true } },
          { property: 'Slug', rich_text: { equals: slug } },
        ],
      },
    })
  const headers = {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${NOTION_API_SECRET}`,
      'Notion-Version': '2022-06-28',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }

  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: body,
    headers: headers,
  })

  const data = await response.json()
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
}
```

`NOTION_API_SECRET` and `DATABASE_ID` are set properly.

200 is expected but not.

Things I tried are as follows:

- Requests to other API, like https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/, are OK
- Trying `export const config = { runtime: 'experimental-edge' }` but 400
- Trying [Edge Runtime CLI](https://edge-runtime.vercel.sh/cli) in the local was OK(200)

Comment: Was dealing with this recently, turned out all I had to do was make a separate API route to call the Notion API that wasn't on the edge runtime, and then call that API route from the original one which is on the edge runtime. This is helpful if you need your original API route to be on the edge runtime like I did to use the @vercel/og library

Comment: @Neesh Thank you for the excellent idea! I implemented separate APIs, one is to respond og-image by using @vercel/og on the Edge Runtime, and the other one is to request Notion API and response its response on the normal environment for the proxy from the Edge Runtime. They works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am having the same issue using the node package, I switched my function from edge back to normal and it is working when deployed.

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const response = await getPosts();

  const scheme = response.scheme;
  const items = response.items;
  res.status(200).json({
    scheme,
    items,
  })
}
```

getPosts() definition

```
import { Client, isFullDatabase } from "@notionhq/client";
import { type } from "os";
const notion = new Client({
  auth: process.env.NOTION_SECRET,
});

const processDatabase = (database) => {
  const notionDatabase = { scheme: "test", items: [] };
  database.results.forEach((result) => {
    const properties = result.properties;
    const row = {
      id: result.id,
      data: {
        name: properties.Name.title[0].plain_text,
        author: properties.Author.rich_text[0].plain_text,
        status: properties.Status.multi_select[0].name,
        start_date: properties.Start.date?.start,
        end_date: properties.End.date?.start,
      },
    };
    notionDatabase.items.push(row);
  });
  return notionDatabase;
};
export async function getPosts() {
  const response = await notion.databases.query({
    database_id: "",
    sorts: [
      {
        property: "Status",
        direction: "ascending",
      },
    ],
  });
  console.log(response);
  return processDatabase(response);
}
```

My edge function last worked 34 days ago on a deployment to vercel. My next deployment was 26 days ago, no longer working and returning 500. All that appears to have changed from my build logs was the Vercel CLI verison from 28.6.0 to 28.8.0, not sure that would even matter.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I implemented as separate APIs as I commented above.